# How can I find record key beginning with an 'a', using LDAP.pm?

Tags: perl, ldap

I am using filter as `(cn=${prefix}*)`, where `$prefix  = 'a';` but still it says 0 records found.

Whereas when I am doing a simple search without this filter, I find many records starting with an `'a'`.

here is some part of the code :- 
    my $prefix = shift();
    my $result = $ldap->search ( base => "$ldapbase",
                                 scope => "sub",
                                 filter => "(objectclass=*)(cn=$prefix*)",
                                 attrs   => ['*']
                               ) or die "error searching tree:$@\n";

my `$ldapbase` gives me details of all the employee, and I want those only which starts with an `'a'`.

Comment: Does the record start with 'a', or the key to the record?

Comment: record key (ex. name ) starts with a

Comment: Which LDAP.pm are you using? There are several.

Comment: What I am really asking: Does the module allow you to use wildcards like that? A bareword `*` means something different, than a quoted `"*"`.

Comment: I am using Net::LDAP http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/perl-ldap-0.4001/lib/Net/LDAP.pod

Comment: From what I can tell, it should work. It's all about how you call it. Put in all the relevant code in the question, including where you use `cn=${prefix}*`. You may want to check out http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4515.txt the part with SubstringFilter.

Answer (score 1):

It might be wise to give the LDAP administrator a heads-up that you intend to be making requests that involve the use of substrings. The LDAP administrator may be able to index CN for substring searches so searches will be faster. The filter `'(cn=a*)'` is a substring filter, and should return all CN attributes from your search base 'downward' (you're using subtree scope in the example) that start with the letters 'a' or 'A' (CN is probably a DirectoryString type and may not have case sensitivity).

From a practical perspective, some older directory servers require more than one character before the substring `'*'` character for substring indexes to work, for example `'(cn=ab*)'` might use indexes on some servers, whereas `'(cn=a*)'` might not use indexes.

In your code example you list the filter `'(objectClass=)(cn=$prefix)'`, which is not a legal LDAP search filter. Perhaps you meant `'(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(cn=${prefix}*))'` (inetOrgPerson might be some other object class) and the code listed is a typo. If you want just the DNs of the entries that begin with 'a' or 'A', you can request the 'special' attribute '1.1', that way just the entry DN and no attributes are returned.

Answer (score 0):

When we find our customers searching for CNs that start with a, often times, the next search we see from them is for a CNs that start with aa.  Back before we had quite so many users, the next search would be for CNs that start with b.

If you really want to look up all of the entries in the database, there's probably a better way to do that.  You may want to talk with your LDAP administrators, it's possible that they have a better way to suggest.  LDAP servers, in general, are designed to perform searches that find a small subset of entries, and while they handle queries with larger result sets OK, depending on the exact server software, they may not handle it very well.

There's also the question if whether or not that's really what you want to be doing.  Most of the time, the reason our users want to pull all of our entries are because they are administrators of some application that wants to have all the user data in its own database.

Sometimes, these applications can be configured to use an external LDAP in an overlay mode, they just need to be configured to do it.  In every case I've been asked to help with a situation like this, the application documentation explicitly said it could do that, but it just wasn't in terms the application administrator recognized as saying that.

Most of the time, the application user base is much smaller than the whole company, and they're trying to pull all of the company's users when they only really need less than 1% of them.  Being able to query on something else that just selects the users desired - like `(departmentnumber=7159)`, for example, would generally work much more optimally.